# Regex for url followed by certain text

Tags: javascript, regex, url

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2bi70xUVP_QeFVjOUdjRXNWNlU
```

I want to replace the above with

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B2bi70xUVP_QeFVjOUdjRXNWNlU
```

For which i am trying to create a regex to detect the first string

My regex:

```
^(http|https):[^\/\/drive\.google\.com\/open\?^id\=$].*$
```

However it doesn't work.

Please help

Comment: What regex tool are you using?

Comment: remove the second ^  : http://www.regexr.com/3c0h5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var str = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2bi70xUVP_QeFVjOUdjRXNWNlU';

var result = str.replace(/^https?(:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/)open\?(id=[^&]+)$/,
             'http$1uc?export=view&$2');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tY3sM3/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is boring, but should meet your needs:

```
var text = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2bi70xUVP_QeFVjOUdjRXNWNlU';
var result = text.replace('https', 'http').replace('open?', 'uc?export=view&');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b46have5/

It looks like you just want to replace `https` with `http` and `open?` with `uc?export=view&`.